# EF1: Where on foreign key of Entity without having to eager load the whole related object

Tags: entity-framework, linq-to-entities

Sorry if this is a really stupid question, or if it's been answered anywhere else but I'm having trouble finding an answer.

I want to be able to filter a list of entities by a foreign key of a related entity without having to eager load that entity using `.Include("ParentEntity")`. This doesn't seem like an edge case to me, selecting a complete object when all I want is the FK, which is hidden - it's even in the returned data when that the generated SQL is executed.

This is what a I want to do:

```
from s in EfContext.Child
where s.Parent.Id == 1
select s;
```

This is what I have to do:

```
from s in EfContext.Child
.Include("Parent")
where s.Parent.Id == 1
select s;
```

Now you may think this isn't a big deal, but when you're dealing with the rubbish that is the Entity Framework inheritance implementation, that Include statement generates several hundred lines of SQL if the entity you're including is the base class to a bunch of other entities :( - So I'm trying to find a workaround.

I found [this tip](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/alexj/archive/2009/03/25/tip-7-faking-foreign-key-properties-in-net-3-5-sp1.aspx) which talks about faking the FK, but it suggests you can't use the faked property in a LINQ statement.

I can't use EF4 either as I'm stuck with .net 3.5 sp1

Thanks all.

**UPDATE:**

So I've developed a work around for my problem, what I'm after is someone to smack me upside the head and tell me that this is a totally ridiculous way of doing things :)

```
    Parent parent = new Parent{Id = 1};
    _ctx.AttachTo("Parent",parent);
    parent.Children.Load();
    //This requirement wasn't in the original question, but I've included for reference 
    foreach (Child child in Parent.Children)
    {
        child.GrandChildReference.Load();
    }

    return from p in parent.Children
           select p;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You say:

> This is what a I want to do:

... and show this code:

```
from s in EfContext.Child
where s.Parent.Id == 1
select s;
```

Have you tried it? This works fine in EF 1. No `Include()` needed.

Comment: You're absolutely right and I feel like a right doosh; that's what you get for trying to solve issues at 3:00 am. The problem I was having is that the View that enumerates the returned object is trying to access the Id of the Parent object, which of course can't be navigated to because, unless you .Include() it, it doesn't exist. What would you suggest as the best way to make reference to the Parent object's ID (that was used to filter) without using .Include()? Perhaps Tip 7 from AlexJ using the EntityKey (that I've referenced in my original daft question)?

Comment: The way I solve this is to create a dedicated view model containing all of the data needed for the view in one, flat type, and then projecting onto that type in an L2E query. This always works (again, no `Include()` needed ), and produces optimal SQL.